# Does HTML have its own regex rules?

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to write an html regex to match a phone number in the format (111)111-1111 but I can't seem to find any reference on how HTML regex's are formatted. Does HTML have its own regex rules? Does it use JS or PHP's regex rules?

This is what I have so far:

```
pattern="([\d]{3})[\d]{3}-[\d]{4}"
```

I've tried using every combination of [0-9] instead of [\d] and backslashing the parentheses and dash in case they are a special character but none of these seem to work

Comment: edit: Still wasn't able to find a reference to html regex rules but using \- seems to have been my problem since it would allow any string if I had that anywhere in the regex

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your parentheses. Like this:

```
pattern="\([\d]{3}\)[\d]{3}-[\d]{4}"
```

Also, you don't need to enclose the `\d` in character class brackets.